# Convert C# String Array to Javascript String Array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-7.0

On an Asp.Net Core 7 project I have a `String` array:

```
Model model = new Model {
  Keys = new() { "a", "b", "c" }
}
```

On a Razor component I need to convert this C# String Array to a Javascript array:

```
<div x-data="{ keys: @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Keys)), step: 1 }">
```

But `Html.Raw` is not recognised. How to do this conversion?

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you post a [mre]? What error do you have?

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem was with the use of quotes. I need to use single quotes on x-data instead of double quotes